# VHDL Syntax error with very simple if then process

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I am trying to make a simple program to turn on an LED when a button is pushed.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TurnOn is
Port ( sig : in STD_LOGIC;
       led : out  STD_LOGIC);
end TurnOn;

architecture Behavioral of TurnOn is

(Line 39) process(sig)
begin

if sig = '1' then
led <= '1';
(Line 44) else
led <= '0';

(Line 47)end if;    
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I get these errors.

```
Line 39: Syntax error near "process".
Line 44: Syntax error near "else".
Line 47: Syntax error near "if".
```

I am new to VHDL so I am assuming that it's something small that I am missing. Been staring at this for about an hour. Thanks for any input.

Comment: you could also omit the whole process and write only the following line: `led <= sig;`. That is a concurrent signal assignment, so these signals are then directly connected. You would still need the missing `begin` though.

Comment: A concurrent statement has an equivalent process, it's actually how they are elaborated for simulation.  You can think of it as short hand for a process statement.  IEEE Std 1076-1993, 9.5 Concurrent signal assignment statements, paragraph 8 and the construction choices d), or -2008, 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements, paragraph 9 and construction choice d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the begin statement before your process declaration.

```
architecture Behavioral of TurnOn is

begin

process(sig)
begin
```